# Different event by clicking on different buttons in listview by row position

Tags: android, listview, button

I have a listview with a custom adapter like this:
[image]

I would like to set different actions for every button in listview, for example switching by position in the listview.  How can i do that?

This is my custom adapter:

```
public class Customadapter extends ArrayAdapter<Formazionicontainer>{

Context context;

public Customadapter(Context context, int resourceId,
        List<Formazionicontainer> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtTitle;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Formazionicontainer rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have an array that you passed to your list view adapter:

```
String[] values = {"Inter","Juventus"};
```

then you can do something like:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
                       switch(position){
                          case 0: // Inter
                                  break;
                          case 1: // Juventus
                                  break;
                       }
        }
    });
```

**//EDIT**

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Formazionicontainer rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(holder);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.item = rowItem;
    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

    /* you can also add on click listener this way to your views
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(YourActivityName.this,
                "I am here at position: " + position,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
*/

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button button;
    Formazionicontainer item;
    TextView txtTitle;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Your things here
    }
}
```

Comment: this way i set the event by clicking on the row, i want to set different listeners for every button in the row

Comment: ok, thats easy ... i cant see your code, but pass in this example values array as an argument through constructor to your custom listview adapter and in getView method implemnt onClickListener for your buttons with logic as i passed in answer above

Comment: you can also edit your qustion and pass there your custom adapter and i can help you :)

Comment: if you are struggling with something just feel free to ask :)

Comment: i'm posting my custom adapter :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is use the ViewHolder as the Button click listener:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Formazionicontainer rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        holder.button = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        // Set the ViewHolder to handle the Button click
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(holder);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());
    // Update the holder item
    holder.item = rowItem;

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView txtTitle;
    ImageView imageView;
    Button button;
    Formazionicontainer item;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Handle the button click here...
        // The item attribute contains the information about the Button's item clicked.
    }
}
```